# Autotest is not loading in ruby on rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, autotest

I am having a problem with autotest. it doesn't seem to load as tutorial videos I have been seeing. this is what happens , it somewhat "freezes" and nothing is happening. As i speak :

```
 $ autotest -rails
 loading autotest/rails_rspec2
```

Also , when I run the server command , it shows that it needs ZenTest 4.8.4

```
rails s
Could not find ZenTest-4.8.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

This is happening . I have installed Zentest 4.8.3 even and sometime ago it was telling me to download Zentest 4.8.4 I had downgraded because of a useful post made by a member in this community to a related question. Still , I don't seem to have any headway. Can anyone please help ? I am a total newbie to programming alone and am getting really dejected that it's getting stuck at such a nascent stage.

Any leads anyone ? reinstalling doesnt work .

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specs?  If you don't have specs, autotest will appear to freeze (just waiting for specs to run).

As for the ZenTest problem.. will you post your Gemfile?  I'm guessing that you're not including ZenTest in a group.

Do you get any different results if you run 'bundle update'